# How can I identify the pin order on this board?

Tags: electrical, wiring, renault, diagram

I'm working on a project on my car, which involves some tinkering with wiring diagrams, pinouts and modules. I'm quite inexperienced with the electrical part of the stuff, so I'm sorry if this question is too obvious for you.

The issue I'm facing is I can't identify the pin order on connectors S1 and S2 on this module, and to make it worse, the drawing in the manual has the positions of the S connectors facing the same way, whereas in the actual part, they face oposite directions, as shown in the photo of the real module. The pin order on the P ports, however, is very clear and identical to the real piece, with the pin order well signaled.

Any help is very appreciated, thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have wiring diagrams for the car that show where each pin is connected to? If so, you could try identifying some ground pins in the P connectors. Then measure for continuity to find ground pins in the S connectors and compare their location with the numbering on the wiring diagram.

Comment: Another note ... the picture and the diagram do not match. They are not of the same control  module. P1 & P2 match, but S1 & S2 do not. You can look at the orientation and spacing of the guides within the housing. Pin numbering might match, but these aren't the same beasts.

Comment: @Unimportant yes, I have all the diagrams, but the problem is I don't have this board yet. It's part of a subsystem that the particular version of my car doesn't have. So, I am trying to understand how it all works before I start buying the parts. If I can't identify the pin order, I'll buy the module and follow your suggestion.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes, that's the biggest problem. This drawing was extracted from the official documentation, which's apparently wrong. I too thought that the part on the PDF was a different one than the one in the image and on the real car, but I searched the whole web, and didn't find a single one that has the same layout of the one on the book. So my conclusion is that it is the same part, but they printed it in the wrong orientation when making the PDF. And that makes it more confusing, because if I follow the logic of the P ports, I'm thinking the pin order will be reversed for top one.

Comment: Have you looked inside the connector (by the pins)? They'll sometimes put the pin number orientation down there just to fool with you, lol.